# How to get a colorbar when plotting in a loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colorbar, scatter

I am making a scatter plot by plotting every point one after another in a loop :

```
for i in range(len(lon_buoy_2)):
   m.scatter(x[i],y[i],20.,marker='o',lw=0., c=IO_buoy_map_log[i],cmap=cm, vmin=-3., vmax = 0.)
```

Therefore, when I try to create the colorbar, it can't since the points I plot are not in an array. I tried plotting it not in a loop, but it fails and this is the easiest way to get the plot I want.

What would be a method to get a colorbar?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `m`. I think you need more code or context.

Comment: Sorry, so m is just because I plot every scatter point on a map. It goes like

    m = Basemap(projection='npstere',boundinglat=65,lon_0=0,resolution='l')
    x,y = m(lon,lat)

So IO_buoy_map_log is an array containing data from 0 to 1, which I wish to plot on the map, with a color representing its value.

Comment: i don't understand why you do this in a loop. The whole point of scatter is to feed it a whole bunch of points and plot them in one go

Comment: Also, you should edit that extra info into your question, rather than leave it in a comment

Answer (score 0):

Doing it not in a loop works fine. Thanks.